# Unable to delete using dbSet - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datacontext, dbset

I am using EF6 and I am trying to delete an entity like this:

```
  public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {

        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
```

But it's giving me error like this:

[image]

Then I used another method like this:

```
    DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

and now the error is something like:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the entity which doesn't exist in `ObjectStateManager`. Try to attach it before trying to remove;

```
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var entry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
```

Also, I don't know how are you fetching the entity instance but don't use `.AsNoTracking()` if you will modify or remove them.

Comment: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Comment: done, i found my mistake actually. I was passing the item selected from datagrid directly to delete method. Now after first fetching the selected item and then passing it to method solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: need to check your DbContext initiation where Delete method exist.